# React Axios get call doesn't work with authorization header

Tags: reactjs, axios, header, authorization

I am working on a Axios get in the react which need authorization.
Before I add the authorization, it worked well, and after I add the authorization header in the backend and frontend, it has CORS error. I tried the get call in the postman and it works very. So I think it shall be Axios get code in the frontend.
Here is Axios get code:

```
async sendGetRequest(variable) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let AuthStr = 'token';
            console.log(typeof(AuthStr)); => the type is String
            Axios.get(`url/${variable}`,{
                header:{
                    'Authorization': AuthStr
                }
            })
                .then(res => {
                    resolve(res.data)
                }
                );
        })
    }
```

I am not sure it's wrong, looks good for me.
Here is my postman result.(I hide the url)
[image]

Comment: Should be headers, you are missing the 's' at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed this post by myself.
Because I made a typo mistake
it  shall be

```
headers:{
          'Authorization': AuthStr
      }
```

Hope it will be helpful for others.